# Setting conditions for a parameter in a class function

Tags: python-3.x, class, for-loop

I am trying to set a condition that only allows an integer value that is greater than 0 to be used when initialising a new class instance. Anything else would return an error.

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        if type(radius) == 'int' and radius > 0:
            self.radius = radius 
        else:
            print("Incorrect value for radius")

circle1 = Circle(2) #output: Incorrect value for radius
circle2 = Circle(-3) #output: Incorrect value for radius
circle3 = Circle('a') #output: Incorrect value for radius
```

Circle 1 should be correct but fails the case, is there something that I am doing incorrect to allow for integer values and integer values greater than 0 to be used for the radius when creating a new circle class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type(arg)` returns the type and not a string of the type.

Instead of `type(radius) == 'int'` you should use `type(radius) == int`

Comment: appreciate the response and solution, it worked.

Comment: @kosh to help others who might come across this question, consider marking the answer as accepted.